# Grease Pencil - Low FPS performance in viewport

Tags: grease-pencil

I've been struggling to find the most efficient way in which to use Grease Pencil in Blender 2.8 drawings as part of an environment. I would be extremely grateful for any suggestions!

I am completely new to Blender 2.8, I’ve been working on 2.79 up until now.

I have a MacBook Pro. 2.4Ghz Intel Core i5, Graphics: Intel Iris 1536, NVIDIA

I've been trying to find a way to manually draw all the elements of the environment (trees, rocks, etc...) with the grease pencil.

Unfortunately whenever I have a small number of grease pencil drawings (even ones with just a few material layers) such as the default Monkey the playback in the viewport slows down all the way to 15 FPS. A big decrease considering it's just a couple of Grease Pencil drawings.

See top left corner.(13.3 FPS)

[image: See top left corner]

I’ve been trying to simplify the drawings with the simplify modifier. I suspected that perhaps the number of points (in the hand-drawn strokes) of the drawing were slowing down the computer, but the FPS were still extremely low even with a simplify modifier with an Interation level of 3.

15.27 FPS

[image: 15.27]

Here’s an example of a quick couple of hand drawn trees with the effect that I’m hoping to achieve. This environment is still in a very early phase and I would like to add hundreds of more drawings to it. Atm this is not possible since the current FPS is all the way down to 4.6. Quite difficult to animate in those conditions :).

[image]

4.40 FPS

I’m surprised that the viewport performance is so low, since when fully rendering the same frame at 40 samples the rendering time is only about 3 seconds.

In comparison, if a session has 100.000 + faces (in terms of meshes) in the session, the FPS performs better than just a couple of Grease Pencil monkeys.

Anyway, I hope it makes some sense! Would be very thankful for any advice or suggestions for what would be the best workflow.

Thank you

Update:

I've tried the most simple version possible of the grease pencil. A straight line with only two points. WEIRDLY enough I get the exact same slow down in FPS as the more complex Monkeys that had several materials and more points in the strokes.

[image]

I've done a test with some high poly meshes to see how the computer behaves in comparison. This session has 331.884 Verts, 331.776 Faces and it doesn't slow down in the viewport: FPS 30.

I only get the slow down with the grease pencil.

[image]

I've tried playing around with the Grease Pencil Object properties and the way it displays in the viewport, but no luck.

Comment: I've tried with my computer (i7 6700, 4 Ghz), and I get some little slowdown (22 FPS) starting from more than 120 animated grease pencil monkeys. Are you sure there isn't something else that's slowing down your machine?

Comment: Thanks josh. Oh wow I wish I could do so many! My computer is a MacBook (2.4 Ghz i5, Graphics Card: Intel Iris 1536, it's supposed to also have NVIDIA I think). Atm it looks like the low FPS only happens with the grease pencil. In comparison 've tried a quick session with 330.000 mesh faces and there's no slow down. I'm attaching a picture of that test in the post. I've tried messing around with many of the properties of the grease pencil, and how it displays in the viewport but i still get the same result. :/